# Doctrine, inconsistens scheme

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

There is an accommodation, and accommodationPool entity. An accommodation may have many accommodationPool.

Accommodation entity:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationPool", mappedBy="accommodation")
 */
protected $accommodationPool;
```

AccommodationPool

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation", inversedBy="accommodationPools", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accommodation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
protected $accommodation;
```

everything works, but schema validator says its inconsistens. Why? I dont really understand Doctrine yet btw

Comment: Avoid bidirectional associations. There are not so many cases when it is really needed

Answer (score 3):

Reading your annotations you've made a few errors, that's what Symfony is telling you.

@JoinColumns is typically for use on a ManyToMany association and not needed on a ManyToOne as there is only one join column.

You've typoed your property, it must match inversedBy exactly.

Re-writing your code:

Accommodation:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Doctrine\Entity\AccommodationPool", mappedBy="accommodation")
 */
protected $accommodationPools;
```

AccomodationPool:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctrine\Entity\Accommodation", inversedBy="accommodationPools", fetch="LAZY")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="accommodation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $accommodation;
```